# dotnet System.Web.Caching.Cache vs System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

I've got a class that needs to store data in a cache.
Originally I used it in an asp.net application so I used System.Web.Caching.Cache.

Now I need to use it in a Windows Service.
Now, as I understand it, I should not use the asp.net cache in a not asp.net application, so I was looking into MemoryCache.

The problem is that they are not compatible, so either I change to use MemoryCache in the asp.net application, or I will need to create an adapter so ensure that the two cache implementations have the same interface (maybe derive from ObjectCache and use the asp.net cache internally?)

What are the implications of using MemoryCache in an asp.net?

Nadav

Comment: +1 interesting question.  The most obvious thing I'd see would be that MemoryCache and the ASP.NET Cache would be competing for memory resources.  This might translate into different behavior when there is memory pressure, as each have independently defined cache item priority.

Answer (score 8):

I would go with your second option and refactor things a little bit. I would create an Interface and two Providers (which are your adapters):

```
public interface ICachingProvider
{
    void AddItem(string key, object value);
    object GetItem(string key);
}

public AspNetCacheProvider : ICachingProvider
{
    // Adapt System.web.Caching.Cache to match Interface
}

public MemoryCacheProvider : ICachingProvider
{
    // Adapt System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache to match Interface
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin, 
This will probably be what I will do.

Comment: It just Irritating that there are two cache implementations in the BCL and they don't have a common interface :(

Comment: Where do you think that Common Interface would live? I suspect Microsoft didn't want to make it that you had to include some System.Runtime.*.dll as a requirement of using System.Web.Caching and likewise they made System.Runtime.Caching because they didn't want people to have to reference System.Web.* from their applications.

Comment: Well, an interface is not such a big thing that you can't put it in one of the base dlls.
Right now, If you want to cache data in a client you don't have anything( System.Runtime.Cache is in the Server profile).

Answer (score 4):

This morning I came across a library that could help with this situation. It's a CacheAdapter that allows you to code against a common interface and swap out the caching mechanism (System.Web.Caching, System.Runtime.Cache, or AppFabric) via configuration.

https://bitbucket.org/glav/cacheadapter

Comment: Yes, I just saw it yesterday :)