# Can you use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in a web app?

Tags: asp.net, .net

System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache is described as a kind of System.Web.Caching.Cache for use in non-web applications, but what's the difference? Is there a reason not to use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in an ASP.Net application?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `System.Runtime.Caching` is actually newer, and is modeled after `System.Web.Caching`, the difference being that you don't have to depend on the System.Web assembly.  Also, `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` is extensible, whereas you cannot inherit from `System.Web.Caching.Cache`

My suggestion is that if you have a common library that is, say, used for both web AND a service (for example), go with `System.Runtime.Caching` so you don't have to include the System.Web fluff (if you don't need it).

Here's some discussion on the topic: [dotnet System.Web.Caching.Cache vs System.RUntime.Caching.MemoryCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882733/dotnet-system-web-caching-cache-vs-system-runtime-caching-memorycache)

MSDN: [System.Runtime.Caching Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)

MSDN: [System.Web.Caching Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can.

As for a reason not to, they aren't exactly the same thing and don't share the same cache priorities, so if you were to use both of them, then in a low memory situation you may find things getting ejected from the cache that you didn't expect.

If you just use one or the other, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that it is optimized for usage in non-asp.net application, since it has no dependancy on System.Web. According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx), another difference is that you can create multiple instances of the MemoryCache class for use in the same application and in the same AppDomain instance.

So, there is really no reason not to just use the System.Web.Caching.Cache in your asp.net application, but yes, you can use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache as well.